# UITableview with two different custom cells overlapping while scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with two different custom cells. One will show normal text message and other with some text and image. I am able to use two different custom cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and able to see two different cells like below
[image]

But whenever i scroll the tableview then the cells are overlapping like below.

[image]

Below is my code

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //minimum size of your cell, it should be single line of label if you are not clear min. then return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;

    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    id cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if ([cell isKindOfClass:[TicketTableViewCell class]]) {
        return 171;
    } else {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }

}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [chatHistoryArr count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *msgTypeStr = [msgTypeArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([msgTypeStr isEqualToString:@"msg"]) {


    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"ChatConversationTableViewCell";

    ChatConversationTableViewCell *cell = (ChatConversationTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];



    if (cell == nil)
    {



                NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChatConversationTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    cell.chatmsgLabel.text = [chatHistoryArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.timeAndDateMsgLabel.text = [timeAndDateMsgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


     return cell;
    }

    else{
        static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TicketTableViewCell";

        TicketTableViewCell *cell = (TicketTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];


        if (cell == nil)
        {


                    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TicketTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
                    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];


        }

        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

        cell.tktMsgTxtView.text = [chatHistoryArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.ticketDateAndTimeLbl.text =[timeAndDateMsgArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];



        return cell;
    }





}
```

No issues in showing data or showing different cells, only problem is overlapping. I have already tried the available solutions but no luck. Below is one of them.

adding the below code in cellForRowAtIndexPath but no use.

```
for(UIView *view in cell.contentView.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

Tried a lot to fix the issue but no luck. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your code of tableViewCell height

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *msgTypeStr = [msgTypeArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([msgTypeStr isEqualToString:@"msg"]) {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    } else {
        return 171;
    }
}
```

It will resolve your overlap issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once

```
NSString *CellIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Cell %d",indexPath.row];

UITableViewCell *cell=[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if (cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me. I am using custom cells. Thanks for reply